# Loading txt file as dictionary into python script

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a txt file (dictionary.txt) that I would like to load into my script as a dictionary. 
How can I do so?

file dictionary.txt

```
{'YAL008W': 25, 'YBR255W': 50, 'YGR164W': 37, 'YGR131W': 40, 'YNL003C': 11,
'YBR135W': 2, 'YBR160W': 6, 'YJL082W': 79, 'YJL142C': 4, 'YPL191C': 38,
 'YGL215W': 31, 'YKL074C': 33, 'YJL077C': 67, 'YKL096W-A': 22, 'YIL124W': 60,
 'YLR364C-A': 2, 'YPL039W': 58, 'YNL170W': 16, 'YGL141W': 62, 'YJL179W': 15,
 'YDR316W-A': 13, 'YDR316W-B': 139, 'YKL083W': 25, 'YOR009W': 25,
 'YKL029C': 395, 'YPL166W': 31, 'YKL052C': 20, 'YOL034W': 29, 'YBL008W': 42,
 'YIL062C': 2, 'YCL023C': 27}
```

Code:

```
f=open('dictionary.txt', 'r') 

with f as dic1:
     dictionary1=eval(dic1.read())
```

This inputs it as a dictionary, but I was wondering if there is a faster way to do so.

Comment: Please submit some code that shows us you tried to do something at least

Comment: I just edited my question. hope that helps

Comment: is this data in a known format? For example, is it supposed to be valid JSON? How was the data created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary)

Comment: I created the data myself. The keys are gene names and values are integer count of reads that mapped to the gene. I created an empty dictionary, saved all gene names into keys and then had a for loop run through and add appropriate number of times a read was mapped to the gene. The dictionary was saved as a .txt file with sys.stdout @BryanOakley

Comment: Side-note: It's extraordinarily weird and partially defeating the purpose of using `with` statements to separate the `open` line from the `with`. You'd almost always combine them into `with open('dictionary.txt') as dic1:` (I omitted the `'r'` since that's the default mode anyway).

Comment: That data is not split up like you have it now, that's only for posting purpose, correct?

Comment: No, it is split it up that way @Leb

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely to be faster, or slower, but you can make it much more secure by avoiding `eval` (which can execute arbitrary code, which makes for a major security and stability risk) in favor of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval); it's like `eval`, but only for Python literals, not arbitrary code. Depending on format, you might also be able to use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) or `json.loads`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dictionary.txt` is almost JSON, so I would recommend something like this:

```
import json
with open('dictionary.txt') as data_file:
    data = data_file.read()
# Convert single quotes to double quotes to get JSON syntax
data = data.replace('\'', '"')
data = json.loads(data)
for key, val in data.iteritems():
    print "%s = %s" % (key, val)
```

For your `dictionary.txt`, this outputs

```
YOL034W = 29
YAL008W = 25
...
YKL052C = 20
```

NOTE: Ellipses have been used to abbreviate the output.